# How to Communicate to a WatchOS App from a MacOS App?

Tags: swift, macos, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

I know how one may communicate between iOS apps and watchOS apps using [Watch Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity). I see it works for Mac Catalyst, but not normal MacOS Apps.

Is there a similar way I could communicate between a macOS app and a watchOS app (using Swift)? I haven't managed to find anything... Please Help!

Comment: Hey did you end up finding anything? I'm dealing with a similar problem. Also, how has your experience been using WC session on a Mac Catalyst app? @PersonDudeGuy

Comment: This could be adapted for macOS as well https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/building_a_custom_peer-to-peer_protocol